# How to run checkov in Windows

Tags: python, checkov

I have installed Python and downloaded checkov using `pip3 install checkov` and get the following error

```
'checkov' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How do I run checkov in Windows?

I have tried installing checkov in my Terraform directory and the default directory. I also added an env path for checkov in the directory I installed it in.

Comment: In case this is helpful for people stuck like I was. Once you download checkov (I used pip install checkov the second time) navigate to the following folder: 
 c:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts  


Once there type checkov --version

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.